# Unable to get json in correct format with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I parse a parameter to a php file and try to get json with file_get_contents().
This is my Code:

```
< ?php
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $url = urldecode($url);
    $json = file_get_contents($url, true);
    echo($json);
? >
```

This is the called URL:
http://vimeo.com/api/v2/channel/photographyschool/videos.json

This is a part of my result:

```
[{"id":40573637,"title":"All For Nothing - \"Dead To Me\" & \"Twisted Tongues\""}]
```

And so on... So everything is escaped. There are even \n in the result.

Since I neet to work afterwards with the json (in js), I need a non escaped version!

Interesting thing is, that my code works for example with this json:
http://xkcd.com/847/info.0.json

What is my problem?

Comment: Everything isn't escaped, quotes internal to quoted strings here are correctly escaped.

Comment: `json_decode()` correctly decodes that JSON file for me, no problems.

Comment: But how do i get the json echo'd so that i could read the result of the php as json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to proxy/forward the response then just echo it as it is with the correct Content-Type header:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $json = file_get_contents('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/channel/photographyschool/videos.json');
    echo $json;
?>
```

Tho you have to be very wary of the url passed as it could cause XSS!

And as the API is slow/resource hungry you should cache the result or at least save it in a session so its not repeated on each page load.

```
<?php
$cache = './vimeoCache.json';
$url = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/channel/photographyschool/videos.json';

//Set the correct header
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour, use it
if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 60*60){
    echo file_get_contents($cache);
}else{
    //Grab content and overwrite cache file
    $jsonData = file_get_contents($url);
    file_put_contents($cache,$jsonData);
    echo $jsonData;
}
?>
```

Comment: is there no way just to "echo" the json in the correct json format so that my php is just printing out what vimeo json is delivering?

Comment: You mean like this? `$json = file_get_contents(...); echo $json;`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
echo json_decode($json);
```

**EDIT:** FORGET the above. Try adding:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

above

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: @PhilippSiegfried yes, `json_decode` will turn the JSON into a PHP array. How are you parsing the JSON in your JS?

Comment: I would like to have the php as some sort of proxy to prevent cross-site-scripting problems when i do an ajax call from a different machine!

Comment: Use `print_r()` instead, maybe?

Comment: then i get Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 40573637 [title] => All For Nothing - "Dead To Me" & "Twisted Tongues"  ... which is no valid json too..

Comment: @MBJ you should know you cant just `echo` an array.

Comment: @PhilippSiegfried If you are using your PHP script as a proxy, that it would just relay the JSON from another server. Why do you need un-escaped strings?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone You know, I should... That was a gray minute in my life.

Comment: I need a valid json as the output of the php file.

Comment: Valid JSON requires special char to be escaped.

Comment: ok please forget about the escaping stuff, i thought it woud be the problem. please just tell me how i get the output of the php that i want (a valid json so that my jsonviewer for example is able to interpret it)

Comment: @PhilippSiegfried Try adding `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` above `$url = $_GET['url'];` and if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You should use json_decode :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

better yet, where you deliver your json use:

```
json_encode(array(
    "id" => 40573637,
    "title" => 'All For Nothing - "Dead To Me" & "Twisted Tongues"'
));
```